# publish website + VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, publish

I created a website using VB.NET on VS2008. When i finished working on it I published it and then deployed it on the production server.
The problem is that when I change any code in the website I need to republish it again and deploy all the items again from scratch.
Is there any other faster way to deploy only a single page or single user control.

I know that if I created a webapplication then all the code will be generated into one single dll, but I have a website.

Comment: In the publish Properties, do you see "Use fixed naming and single page assemblies"? If so, when you choose this you should be able to update only the one single changed DLL file.

Comment: I checked it, now on every publish the same set of dlls are generated. I think this solved my problem.

Comment: Cheers, added this as answer as well for better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the publish Properties, check "Use fixed naming and single page assemblies".

This would let you update only the one single changed DLL file of the page/control you have updated.